# java - error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java with this website: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html
But when I run the code in Ubuntu through the terminal I get these errors:

```
vonvic@BSW-Computer:~/Java_Applications$ javac StringVariables2.java
StringVariables2.java:3: error: '{' expected
    public static class main(String[] args) {
                        ^
StringVariables2.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name")
                      ^
StringVariables2.java:8: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name")
                           ^
StringVariables2.java:8: error: ';' expected
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name")
                                                      ^
StringVariables2.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.println("Please enter your family name")
                      ^
StringVariables2.java:12: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("Please enter your family name")
                       ^
StringVariables2.java:12: error: ';' expected
    System.out.println("Please enter your family name")
                                                       ^
StringVariables2.java:16: error: <identifier> expected
    full_name = first_name +" "+ family_name;
             ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                      ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                       ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: ')' expected
        System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                                ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: ';' expected
            System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                                  ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                                            ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: <identifier> expected
        System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                                             ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
                                              ^
StringVariables2.java:20: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
16 errors
vonvic@BSW-Computer:~/Java_Applications$
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringVariables2 {

    public static class main(String[] args) {

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

    String first_name;
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name")
    first_name = user_input.next();

        String first_name;
        System.out.println("Please enter your family name")
        first_name = user_input.next()

        String full_name;
        full_name = first_name +" "+ family_name;

        System.out.println("You are" + full_name);
    }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander.

---

Now I get this:

```
vonvic@BSW-Computer:~/Java_Applications$ javac StringVariables2.java

StringVariables2.java:13: error: variable first_name is already defined in method     main(String[])
    String first_name;
           ^
StringVariables2.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    full_name = first_name + " " + family_name;
                                   ^
  symbol:   variable family_name
  location: class StringVariables2
2 errors
```

Comment: Use a full IDE. Don't write code in text editor.

Comment: You are missing semi-colons one some lines.

Comment: Ubuntu is entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a long, long list of compilation failures.

Comment: The "Now I get this:" error messages mean exactly what they say. Read them carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you forgot to add semi-colons to the end of some of your statements:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your first name");

System.out.println("Please enter your family name");
first_name = user_input.next();
```

Edit:

Your `main` should also be a method (not a class)

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: +1 That is the cause of some of the syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare main as a method, not a class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Declaring main as a class put several executable statements at the top level inside that class, where only declarations are permitted.